# Application comes to foreground from background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios

When application comes to foreground from background then appixationDidBecomeActive gets called. Now, I want to refresh the page from which the home button was tapped. In which method I can write the refresh code. viewWillAppear is not getting called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case `viewWillAppear` never gets called, you can fire notification(s) whenever `-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application` gets called and use it on the view you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom notification like : NSNotificationCenter. 
And on call of this you can refresh your view.